# Filter JSON API data based on the item selected in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

Good day, I am currently working on an Ionic 2 app and I am having difficulty in filtering the data base on the selected item on the dropdown menu.

Here is my code:

TS file:

```
    this.http.get('http://sample.com/xxx/api.php/address_province?transform=1')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
    this.province = data.address_province;
    console.log(this.province);
}, (err) => {
    console.log("Something went wrong.");
});


this.http.get('http://sample.com/xxx/api.php/address_city?transform=1')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
    this.city = data.address_city;
    console.log(this.city);
}, (err) => {
    console.log("Something went wrong.");
});
```

Template

```
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Province</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="registerprovince" >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let prov of province" value="{{prov.province_description}}">{{prov.province_description}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>City</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="registercity" >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let cities of city" value="{{cities.city_description}}">{{cities.city_description}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

[image]

What I wanted to do is that when I choose a province in the province-dropdown menu, Only the cities under the province will be shown in the city-dropdown menu.

[image]

I still have no idea how will I implement this kind of filtering in my code. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose city object have *provinceName* property, you can intercept the ionChange event of ion-select and do cities filtering whenever province changes:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Province</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="registerprovince" (ionChange)="onProvinceChange($event)>
        <ion-option *ngFor="let prov of province" value="{{prov.province_description}}">{{prov.province_description}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>City</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="registercity">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let city of filteredCities" value="{{city.city_description}}">{{city.city_description}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

// In your component's class:

filteredCities = [];

onProvinceChange(selectedProvince: any) {
    console.log('Selected', selectedProvince);
    this.filteredCities = this.cities.filter(city => city.provinceName === selectedProvince.province_description);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://sample.com/xxx/api.php/address_city?transform=1')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.cities = data.address_city;
            this.filteredCities = data.address_city;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Something went wrong.");
        });
}
```